# Scan peripheral on background

Tags: iphone, background

My BLE app running on background and scanning peripheral but the delegate method `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:` not callback. I've setted the value in Info.plist for `UIBackgroundModes`. Why? How to solve it?

Comment: This is the same question as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749580/never-seen-anything-in-corebluetooth-framework-about-keeping-the-connection-aliv/22251385#22251385).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scan for peripherals in background mode,
just open connection to peripherals and keep references to that peripherals.

After that you can call

```
[peripheral1 readRSSI];
```

And wait for CBPeripheralDelegate callback

```
peripheralDidUpdateRSSI:
```