# What is meant by serviceUUIDs when scanning bluetooth?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Sorry for bad english :-(

I am starting with CoreBluetooth framework. i using write code like below for CoreBluetooth

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

I took a look into apple reference, I do not understand that what's that **serviceUUIDs**?

```
- (void)scanForPeripheralsWithServices:(NSArray *)serviceUUIDs options:(NSDictionary *)options;
```

Please explain me.

Answer (score 2):

The NSUUID class creates UUID strings that are to uniquely identify types, interfaces, and other items.

UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique Identifiers) or IIDs (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit values. UUIDs created by NSUUID conform to RFC 4122 version 4 and are created with random bytes.

more [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Note:

It is Available from iOS 6

updated:

**UUID**

The Bluetooth-specific UUID of the service. (read-only)

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CBUUID *UUID
```

**Discussion**

This property is a 128-bit UUID that identifies the service.

**Note:**

Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Comment: This is what a *UUID* is, but what is a *Service UUID*? Bluetooth UUIDs are *not* simply random opaque identifiers.

Comment: @iDev How to find UUDID when start app first time?

Comment: I cant find UUID in CBCentralManager class. How to get list of bluetooth device?

Comment: retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers and retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices @Tajrajan

Comment: @iDev i dnt understand it. Please see  url below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749580/never-seen-anything-in-corebluetooth-framework-about-keeping-the-connection-aliv

Comment: @iDev never call didDiscoverPeripheral while app background mode. Some bodies told me that problem of scanForPeripheralsWithServices methods. How do get to call didDiscoverPeripheral while background mode. Do u know that? Please help me.

Comment: refer this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-core-bluetooth-practical-lesson--mobile-20741

Comment: @iDev Yes, I know that, but it is only for foreground. Never working Background mode. I can send u project. Can u check it? Please.

Comment: where you sent i never get till

Comment: rajapitchai.p@gmail.com

Comment: @iDev sorry, u can download my simple project. Can u check it please. what i should do next coding. link below  https://www.dropbox.com/s/cndj5tgdiw3svw6/EYSensorTagEx.zip plz download

Comment: @iDev if u get any problem. Plz mail me tajrajaniosdeveloper@gmail.com

Comment: Are you sure you're working with Bluetooth Low-Energy? Because if you don't understand an UUID, that's quite troublesome.